# Custom Highcharts legend symbol

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to override the legend symbols in Highcharts. But I cannnot see any way of doing this. The [Highcharts Legend API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend) has a "labelFormatter" function but nothing to format the symbol. My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ebnu4bu/).

My code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

You can see the legend symbol for Tokyo is a blue circle with a line running through it. I want to override this with my own custom legend.

The Legend API allows you to set properties such as symbol width (symbolWidth), padding (symbolPadding) etc. But seeminlgy there is no way to actually replace the symbol.

There is a property "useHTML" which sounds useful. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
The legend needs to change, but the marker on the graph should not

Comment: You can draw it by yourself, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/legend-custom-symbol/

Comment: You can specify a marker symbol for your serie as well: http://jsfiddle.net/5ebnu4bu/1/ But as you will see, it's also displayed on the line

Comment: @Pimskie yes i know that, problem is marker on the chart and in legend wont be the same

Comment: @Ivan This looks like only way to do it arlight, even if a bit messy

Comment: may I ask why you need a legend symbol which does not match the series symbol? Just curious, because the whole point of a legend is to explain which is series is what, like keys for a map (not java map, but an actual map).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two series, connect them using `linkedTo` option, then for the main series, you can use image as symbol, for example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  series: [{
    data: [],
    id: 'main',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
    }
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    data: [1, 3, -2, -4]
  }]
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hnc27nf2/

Screenshot:

[image: exmaple]

Comment: This is good but this will change the marker on the chart AND on the legend. I only want to change the legend