# How to have legends in Pie charts as data labels in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a couple of questions while dealing with Pie Charts in High charts.

1. How to change the legend's shape apart from the circle.
2. I want to display legends in data labels prior to percentage values. [image: sample image]
3. And also with an increase in data, data labels are not radical to the pie chart. How to fix this.

my chart options :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
   
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.percentage:.1f} %'
            },
            showInLegend: true
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels: {
        connectorWidth : 0
        },
        showLegends: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
           
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }]
    }]
});
```

[my code pen](https://codepen.io/chay2443/pen/rNLoXKo)

Would be grateful if I get an answer to any of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The API allows customizing the legend symbol by setting options like `symbolRadius` or `symbolHeight`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1m98xgvr/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolHeight

If you want to change the legend symbol to the custom png try to use this solution:

[Custom Highcharts legend symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302395/custom-highcharts-legend-symbol)

---

2. You can set the `dataLabels.useHTML` flag to true and use the  `dataLabes.formatter` callback to customize the output which will be an outstanding HTML element.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2sog3znq/

---

3. Here I am not sure what do you have in mind - could you explain it more precisely?